# How do I draw a vertical line inside an expandable content RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm fronting a problem to draw a vertical line inside a relative layout as a list item layout like this:

[image: list view item layout, what do i whant]

layout's height is changes from item to item, here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip" 
        android:text="Button"></Button>

<TextView android:id="@+id/title" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="@color/black" 
          android:text="TextView"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/expandable_text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@+id/title" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:textColor="@color/black" 
          android:text="Some expandable text"></TextView>

<View android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
      android:layout_width="5dip" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
      android:background="@color/orange"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the vertical line is not visible / working, any suggestions?
**Thanks in advance!**

p.s
note that this problem has been solved when doing it with LinearLayout, but I had performances issues due to nested views in the layout, and the only solution is in using RelativeLayout, also, the TextViews lines is changing from item to item.

**Solution #1**
After searching for a while, and using the suggested answers posted here (thanks..)
I've found a solution, **which seems to be pretty ugly**, but due to problems with filling a
RelativeLayout using "fill_parent" height, while the layout height itself sets to "wrap_content", it seems to be a reasonable option.

The idea is to takes the uppermost view (the button) and the bottom most view (the expandable text), and use them as anchors alignments to the height of the vertical line.
as you can see in this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:paddingTop="3dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip" 
        android:text="Button"></Button>

<TextView android:id="@+id/title" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
          android:paddingTop="3dip"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="@color/black" 
          android:text="TextView"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/expandable_text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@+id/title" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
          android:paddingBottom="10dip"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:textColor="@color/black" 
          android:text="Some expandable text"></TextView>

<View android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
      android:layout_width="5dip" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_item_task_statusbutton"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_item_task_description"
      android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
      android:background="@color/orange"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note for the changes in the views, especially the replacement of "android:marginXXXX=value" 
with "android:paddingXXXX=value" for fixing the views positions.

Thanks.. and Good Day!

Comment: Does the problem happen only if the text is long enough to overlap the line?

Comment: no, I've tested it in different sizes of the textviews and lines

Comment: It shows the line in my graphical layout preview in eclipse. Check your installation.

Comment: I Know... but when you install the application on emulator / real device it disappears.

Comment: what is list_item_task_statusbutton and list_item_task_description?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had the same issue and took me an hour to find out. You have to put your `RelativeLayout` into a `LinearLayout`. So your code should look like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <View
    android:id="@+id/drawerVerticalLine"
    android:layout_width="10dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#7fa9c5"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
         <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
               android:paddingTop="3dip" 
               android:layout_marginTop="3dip" 
               android:text="Button"></Button>
        ...
      </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And by padding or aligning the `drawerVerticalLine` you get the result you want.

Comment: What if the line should be between other views?I'm having this problem when trying to put the view between a relativelayout and linearlayout.

Comment: just put the relativelayout into a linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:orientation="vertical"` line from `RelativeLayout` tag. Then I think the line should be visible.

Comment: Then there is no reason for it to not be visible.

Comment: I agree with you, but i guess it's a system / logic issue with RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to extend the size of the layout.  `android:orientation` isn't used by RelativeLayout and will be ignored.

Comment: doesn't work. the weird thing is that in LinearLayout it works like a charm even if the layout height is set to "wrap content".
Maybe it's an issue in the android system, i'll check that..


thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a logic You can use the TableLayout, And in that you can use view for seperating the each row with horizontal line. . .
For more information and Tablelayout see this: [Click me](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)